# Display dynamic number of Divs inside another Div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed following javascript code,

```
for (var x = 0; x < address.length; x++) { 
    var dynamic_address = "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mob-no-pad'>" +
        "<div class='address-blk'><span>1</span><p class='store-name'>" + storename[x] + ",</p>" +
        "<address>" + address[x] + "</address>" +
        "<p>Sent to : <a href=''>Email</a> | <a href=''>Text</a> | <a href=''>Get directions</a></p> </div></div>";   
    $("#location-address").html(dynamic_address);           
}
```

```html
<div id="location-address"></div>
```

My question is when I run this code final address of the address array and final value of the storename array are  displayed in location-address div (only one div). Address.length has dynamic value. How can I display all three(any number) divs, Not just one div?

Comment: use `append` then `html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the `html()` method which will overwrite any previous value in the element, hence only the last element of the loop is shown. You need to use `append()` instead:

```
$("#location-address").append(dynamic_address);
```

If needed, you may also need to use `empty()` to clear the content of `#location-address` before running through the loop to update the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamic_address="";
for (var x = 0; x < address.length; x++) { 
     dynamic_address += "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mob-no-pad'>" +
        "<div class='address-blk'><span>1</span><p class='store-name'>" + storename[x] + ",</p>" +
        "<address>" + address[x] + "</address>" +
        "<p>Sent to : <a href=''>Email</a> | <a href=''>Text</a> | <a href=''>Get directions</a></p> </div></div>";   

} 
 $("#location-address").html(dynamic_address);
```